# How do I get user input in Apple's Swift language in a command line tool?

Tags: swift

I am new to Apple programming and I thought I'd try out Swift, but I have no idea how to get user input and store it in a variable. I am looking for the simplest way to do this, something like input() and raw_input() in Python.

```
# Something like this (Python code)
name = raw_input() # name is a string
print "Your name is ", name
number = input() # number is an int or float
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually not easy in Swift at this point.  The simplest way is probably the Objective-C way, using an NSFileHandle with standard input:

```
import Foundation

var fh = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()

println("What is your name?")
if let data = fh.availableData {
    var str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Your name is \(str)")
}
```

Or for continuous input:

```
println("I will repeat strings back at you:")
waitingOnInput: while true {
    if let data = fh.availableData {
        var str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(str)
    }
}
```

The possible encodings are shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_156).

Comment: you don't need label `waitingOnInput:` in this case (and it confused me when I first read it)

Comment: i know it's not needed but i personally find it makes the point of the loop more obvious