# How to get Int value from String Swift 2.0

Tags: input, type-conversion, swift2

Basically I'm getting the user to input a number 1-3 and I want to take the user's inputted number and compare it with a random number. This is my code:

```
func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as!         String
}

var userInput = input()
var userNumber: Int? = Int(userInput)
```

When I try to print userNumber it returns "nil"
any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: What does `userInput` get outputted as?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read input from a cocoa/foundation tool console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869802/read-input-from-a-cocoa-foundation-tool-console)

Answer (score 1):

**I'm Dutch, so my English isn't very good. Sorry for that.** 
*This is the answer that works:*

```
import Foundation

print("What is your age?")
var fhcpy: NSData? = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData

if let data = fhcpy{
    var str: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
    var numstr: String = ""
    for char in str.characters {
        if Int("\(char)") != nil {
            numstr.append(char)
        }
    }
    var num: Int? = Int(numstr)
    if let opNum = num {
        print("Your age is \(opNum)")
    } else {
        print("That is not a valid number. ")
    }
}
```

**How I have done it**
First, I tred the Swift 1.0 method, but that did cause a error ([Get input in swift 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112718/how-do-i-get-user-input-in-apples-swift-language-in-a-command-line-tool)). It was the `if let` method ([Error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743758/swift-2-error-handling-and-while)). after that, I have made a optional called `fhcpy` with the `NSDate` value of `fh.availbleData`. Which solved the problem of the `if let`. Now we want to get an `Int` value ([Get Int value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739460/toint-removed-in-swift-2)). Now we do that with Int(), but it returns every time `nil`. We use a for to look what is inside the variable `str`. 
*Code:*

```
import Foundation

print("What is your age?")
var fhcpy: NSData? = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData

if let data = fhcpy{
    var str: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
    for char in str.characters {
        print(char)
    }
    var num: Int? = Int(str)
    print("Your age is \(num)")
}
```

*Output:*

```
What is your age?
12
1
2


Your age is nil
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Did you see the newline? So we program a `for` that tests for "If a character in the string is an `Int` the `Character` will be append to the `strnum`". At the end, the `strnum` is exported to an `Int`.

*Sample code:*

```
import Foundation

print("What is your name?")
var fhcpy: NSData? = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData

if let data = fhcpy{
    var str: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

    print("Your name is \(str)")
}
```

Comment: Use in place of `fhcpy`, `fhad` (file handle available Data). Which is a lot more universal.

Comment: Also, "the answer that works" is not specialized on the Int value. Becaus if you enter `#%@3!$#5`, it wil display: `Your age is 35`. But now you know that there is a `"\n"` after the input.

Answer (score 0):

It might cause of syntax ordering. Parse string to int and print result would be faster than fetch user input. I suggest you to make completion closure, something like below code.

```
inputTest({
    (result: String?) in
    print("got back: \(result)")
    var userNumber: Int? = Int(result!)
    print(userNumber)
})

func inputTest(completion: (result: String?) -> Void) {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData

    completion(result: NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initializer `Int()` is basically correct but could return `nil` because for example letters cannot be converted to an integer representation. So you have to perform a check

```
let userInput = "Hello" 
if let userInputInteger = Int(userInput) {
  print("OK")
  // do something with userInputInteger
} else {
  print("\(userInput) cannot be converted to integer")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
var userNumber: Int = userInput.toInt()!
```

Comment: The question is addressing Swift 2.0 as `.toInt()` was removed from `String`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30773127/5181636